# Почему в C# такой неудобный enum?

Tags: c#, enum

Есть ли возможность использовать шарповый энум как в плюсах? Вот что я имею ввиду:

```
enum exampleEnum
{
    CELL1,
    CELL2,
    CELL3
}

void Foo ()
{
    int exampleArray [3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    exampleArray[CELL1] = 23;
    ...
    exampleArray[CELL3] = 88;
    ...
}
```

Не понимаю как без крестового энума жить.

Comment: `exampleArray[(int)exampleEnum.CELL1] = 23;`

Comment: Enum придуман как раз для того что бы отличаться от Int, если нужен Int, используйте константы. (кресты тоже в этом направлении двигаются - class enum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как привести `enum` к `int` уже написали. Предложу альтернативу.

Использовать перечисление как ключ может быть удобнее через [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<ExampleEnum, int>();
dict[ExampleEnum.CELL1] = 23;
...
dict[ExampleEnum.CELL3] = 88;
...
//вывод словаря с проверкой существования
foreach(ExampleEnum cell in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExampleEnum))) {
    Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(cell) ? dict[cell] : 0);
}
```

Словарь будет работать медленнее массива, но, учитывая крайне малое количество ключей, разница видится несущественной.

Бонус: этот код не понадобится править если в перечислении изменится порядок  или добавятся новые значения.

Бонус2: словарь проверяет что ключ `ExampleEnum`, а не случайный `int` что позволит избежать ошибок:

```
exampleArray[1]++; //что это?
exampleArray[OtherEnum.NOT_CELL] = 15; //почему?
```

Comment: Я когда увидел вопрос, тоже сразу подумал о словаре. Плюсую.

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так

```
void Foo ()
{
    int[] exampleArray = { 0, 0, 0 };
    exampleArray[Convert.ToInt32(exampleEnum.CELL1)] = 23;
    ...
    exampleArray[Convert.ToInt32(exampleEnum.CELL3)] = 88;
    ...
}
```

---

C# лишён черт слабой типизации к которым вы привыкли в С++. Поэтому это и есть нормальный способ, приведения значения перечисления к `Int32`. Если вы желаете избежать конвертации, а значит хотите использовать значение перечисление как индекс коллекции, то вы можете реализовать свою коллекцию.

```
class ExampleEnumCollection<T> 
{
    private readonly T[] _inner;

    public T this[exampleEnum index]
    {
        get { return _inner[(int)index]; }
        set { _inner[(int)index] = value; }
    }        

    public ExampleEnumCollection(int count, T defaultValue)
    {
        _inner = new T[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            _inner[i] = defaultValue;
        }            
    }
}

void Foo2()
{
    var exampleCollection = new ExampleEnumCollection<int>(3, 0);
    exampleCollection[exampleEnum.CELL1] = 23;
    exampleCollection[exampleEnum.CELL3] = 88;
}
```

Comment: Это я знаю, вот только это жутко неудобно: конвертировать в инт, ещё и прописывать имя энума. Неужели нет нормального способа?

Comment: @Mournehowl может ну эту сишку, переходите на `php`, у нас тут с типизацией все хорошо :)

Comment: @Mournehowl, а по-моему, как раз в плюсах и неудобно. Обращение к элементу энума без указания самого энума только запутывает код